# Kendo UI grid header disappears/shifts on page refresh

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I have a kendoui grid that is being populated from a json datasource.

Everytime my page reloads and refreshes the grid, I see that the header moves to the left, leaving the rightmost column without a header! Has anyone seen that issue? I have not been able to find an answer to this particular situation on SO.

Here is my grid. I would post screenshots too but I don't have the reputation points for that!

Appreciate any help.

```
$("#rgrid").kendoGrid({
            sortable: true,
            selectable: true,
            scrollable: false,
            pageable: {
                pageSize: 10,
                refresh: true
            },
            dataSource: {
                transport: {
                    read: "./php/rd.php?action=grd&email=" + $("#tbvalue").val()
                },               
                schema: {
                    model: {
                        fields: {                            
                            c1: {editable: false},
                            c2: {editable: false},
                            c3: {editable: false ,type: "date"},
                            c4: {editable: false, type: "date"},
                            c5: {editable: true, type: "date"}, 
                            c6: {editable: true},
                            c7: {editable: false}                            
                        }
                    },                  
                    data: "data",
                    total: function(response) {
                        return response.total; // total is returned in the "total" field of the response
                    }
                }
            },
            dataBound: function(e) {
                var grid = $("#rgrid").data("kendoGrid");              
                grid.hideColumn(1); // hide the c2 column                
            },
            columns: [
                {
                    field: "c1",
                    title: "c1",
                    width: 150
                }, 
                {
                    field: "c2",
                    title: "c2"
                },
                {
                    field: "c3",
                    title: "c3",
                    format: "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}"
                }, 
                {
                    field: "c4",
                    title: "c4",
                    format: "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}"
                }, 
                {
                    field: "c5",
                    title: "c5",
                    format: "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}"                
                }, 
                {
                    field: "c6",
                    title: "c6",
                    editor: dropDownEditor
                }, 
                {
                    field: "c7",
                    title: "c7"
                },
                { 
                    command: { text: "View", click: doAction}, title: " ", width: "140px" 
                }
            ],
            editable: true
)};
```

Comment: I'd like to add that the first column (c1) remains intact even on more than 8(total number of columns) reloads!

Comment: comment out `grid.hideColumn(1);` and see what happens

Comment: I copied your code and tried to reproduce what you say and I haven't seen any shift. Could you try to reproduce it in JSFiddle / JSBin and share the link with us?

Comment: @OnaBai Thanks for trying, I didn't post it on jsfiddle because I have a lot of php calls in my code. But to reproduce it, you could add a button that reloads the grid and you'll see how the column gets hidden

Comment: @dcodesmith Thank you! That was it! I thought I had tried that earlier. Any idea though how I would hide that column without losing a new column on every refresh?

Comment: Do you mind me knowing why you want to hide it? @DivyaSankaran

Comment: The column is actually an id field that i don't want to show to the user but I need it for processing the last command column

Comment: I have this problem but I don't have any hidden column and grid header shifts on page refresh.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want a column to do not be displayed, instead of have to manually hide it, you should set [`hidden`](http://docs.kendoui.com/api/web/grid#configuration-columns.hidden) to true in the `columns` definition.

```
<div id="grid"></div>
<script>
$("#grid").kendoGrid({
    columns: [
        { hidden: true, field: "id" },
        { field: "name" }
    ],
    dataSource: [ { id: 1, name: "Jane Doe" }, { id: 2, name: "John Doe" } ]
});
</script>
```

Comment: Awesome! Thanks guys.

Removing hidecolumn(1) and hiding the column in the column definition, solved my problem.

Thanks again.

Comment: Thanks @dcodesmith also for your comment, I can't mark a comment as the answer, but thanks for your help